# Ping in android

Tags: android, if-statement, android-studio, ping

I had seen in stackoverflow this and I find many results, but any of those answer worked for me

But one of those codes works in %50

```
public void GET3() {
    TextView SYS3;

    String ip = "www.codelow-dat.site90.com";
    String pingResult = "";
    String pingCmd = "ping" + ip;

    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = r.exec(new String[]{"ping", "-c 4", "www.codelow-dat.site90.com"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    SYS3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SYS3);
    SYS3.setText(getString(R.string.goingloop)); //going loop
    try {
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            pingResult = inputLine;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SYS3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SYS3);
    SYS3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#66CD00"));
    if (Boolean.valueOf(pingResult) == null) {
        SYS3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D61D00"));
        SYS3.setText(getString(R.string.somethingwrong)); //something is wrong
    } else {
        SYS3.setText(pingResult + getString(R.string.IsOk)); //, is OK
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The "if" is not working anyway I try anything but not work. When the ping is wrong, only seens to me the string IsOk (, is OK) instead of the string somethingwrong (something is wrong) (and change the color of the text to red)

Thanks for all

Comment: Did you try checking if the boolean was false, not just null?

Comment: Yes I try it, but the same; the first time that tried, I put false instead of null...